# how to export visible columns of my datatable

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-5

I have a datatable export option pdf excel but  I have some hidden columns I don't want to see them in the export
this is my code

```
 //Buttons examples
                var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
    
               lengthChange: false,
                    
                    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
                    retrieve: true
                });
                
                
                     table.buttons().container()
                        .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
                // Key Tables

                $('#key-table').DataTable({
                    keys: true
                });
```

I tried to add option
Visible
but didn't work please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `exportOptions` with the `columns` option.

You can provide an array of column index numbers for this - for example:

```
  var colsToExport = [1, 2, 3]; // the first column has an index of 0

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'pdf', 
        text: 'To PDF',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: colsToExport
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel', 
        text: 'To Excel',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: colsToExport
        }
      }
    ]
  } );
```

If you need something more sophisticated than a simple array list, then there are various alternatives to defining an array - see [column-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) for full details.

A full list of export options, in addition to `columns`, can be found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()).